# multi dimensional points in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, spatial, kdtree, spatial-index

Lucene added [multi dimensional point support](https://www.elastic.co/blog/lucene-points-6.0) in 6.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-7494

How can I can use this in Solr? I am hoping for a "simple end to end example"  It would be a worthy blog post.

1) define in the schema

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field-type" : {
    "name":"mypoint",
    "class":"solr.DoublePointField" //is this right? 
}}' http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/schema

curl -XPOST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field":{
    "name":"coords",
    "type":"mypoint",
    "stored":true,
    "indexed":true
  }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/schema
```

2) post data

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{
  "id": "1",
  "coords": "1.5 -0.2222 14213 here I can use my n-dimensional point?",
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/update/json/docs
```

3) do a point range or distance query

```
???  I don't know how to do this.
```

Update:  I ended up using postgresql, which supports k-d tree euclidean distance search through the [cube](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/cube.html) plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing, it has not been implemented yet.  The underlying Lucene layer has it.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11077

Comment: Thank you!  I'll just have to use Lucene in that case.

Comment: Or you could add a Solr FieldType that does what you want. It's not hard. There's even tricks to avoid adding the QueryParser part if you control the FieldType; although writing a QueryParser is one of the easiest things to do in Solr.

Comment: SOLR-8396 covers single-dimensional only.